# rails 4 where method for date on a datetime field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, where-clause

I'm curious if there's a way to use the `where` method without invoking Postgres to find a datetime from a date.

I've been accomplishing this by just injecting SQL but was wondering if there were a railsy way of accomplishing the same thing that I've been overlooking (as I've been doing this a lot).

```
SomeModel.where("start_at::timestamp::date = ?", '2012-01-01') #where start_at is a DateTime column
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm... well you could use a range to span across the entire day:

```
SomeModel.where(start_at: date.beginning_of_day..date.end_of_day) #date = "2012-01-01".to_date
```

Not sure there's an cleaner way than that.